# Manhwa where the emperor prefers another girl over his own (black haired) daughter and his daughter ends up killing him

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, reincarnation, webcomics

This is a manwha my friend told me about and we still cannot find it. The FL is a princess and in her first life her father prefers another girl over her and neglects her, eventually ending up with the FL killing him. In their second life the father remembers what he did in his past life and tries to apologize and make it up to his daughter, however she manipulates him and makes it so the empire hates him and wants his head.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where would your friend have read this?

Comment: At what point in story does the father remember the events of the past life? Early on or dozens of chapters in? And who manipulates him, the FL or the other girl? I don't know if the other details match, and the FL isn't a princess, but "father ignores black-haired daughter over another girl" might be "I was the real one".